# I messed up grub ubuntu 12.04

Tags: grub2, command-line, burg

I was playing around with super boot manager and it's pretty gui features, and ended up messing up everything. I had it working really well before I started messing with super boot manager.

Previous grub/burg setup had Ubuntu, Fedora, and Windows 7 in it. But now it only shows Windows.

The last thing I did was apply a fix to the grub2 via super boot manager(shouldn't have done that).

I am able to get to the grub terminal from burg, but I don't know any commands from there. If I could at least boot into ubuntu I'm pretty sure I can fix the rest.

Can anybody help with this?

Also, I can't remember the exact partition I need to get into ex: (hd0, sdb1) something like that. So some commands to get that info would help as well!

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I missed the last sentence... if you are running from the liveCD, the best way to to get a list of all your partitions is to run `sudo blkid` from a terminal command line.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to get the [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/), which can fix this automatically. It's saved me many times in the past. It can be done with the original Ubuntu install disk, too. And if you know the commands and your partitions, you can boot from the grub prompt, but that's not very intuitive until you've done it a few times.

Comment: Ya I think I will have to go with that option.

Answer (score 1):

You can also boot from a Ubuntu Live CD, and install the boot-repair package via ppa. See this link for more information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... where can he install the boot-repair package?  Not on the CD, and even if he could install it to his existing Ubuntu, it wouldn't help.  Are you simply giving him an alternate location to get the ISO?  If so, that really doesn't qualify as an answer, but should have been a comment, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I was talking about the live session. Boot from the live CD, open the terminal, install the package, run boot-repair. It was just another option for him. Most people already have a Ubuntu disk burnt, so it might be faster.

Comment: I was asking what you meant by "install the package"?  To the live CD?  I don't think so.  To the unreachable partition?  An exercise in frustration, it would seem.  Download and burn the ISO?  That was my answer, but I gave the source for latest version from the site that distributes it, and you gave a different source.